# Python / Pandas : concatenate two dataframes with multi index

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes with same index & columns. (x, y)

```
>>> x
    A   B
0  A0  B0
1  A1  B1

>>> y
    A   B
0  A2  B2
1  A3  B3
```

I found out how to concatenate two dataframes with multi-index as follows. (z)

```
>>> z = pd.concat([x, y], keys=['x', 'y'], axis=1)
>>> z
    x       y
    A   B   A   B
0  A0  B0  A2  B2
1  A1  B1  A3  B3
```

But I want to make the following format of dataframe (target )

```
>>> target
    A       B
    x   y   x   y
0  A0  A2  B0  B2
1  A1  A3  B1  B3
```

I have two questions

1. Is there a nice way to get the 'target' dataframe directly from the x, y ?
2. Is there a nice way to get the 'target' datafrme from z by changing the level of columns?

Thank you for considering my questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) with [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
z = pd.concat([x, y], keys=['x', 'y'], axis=1).swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
print (z)
    A       B    
    x   y   x   y
0  A0  A2  B0  B2
1  A1  A3  B1  B3
```

For another answer is possible define `dictionary of DataFrames` for keys:

```
z = pd.concat({'x':x, 'y':y}, axis=1).swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your very quick answer.  'swaplevel'  was what i need to find.

Answer (score 2):

I just learn it recently `reorder_levels` :-)

```
pd.concat([x,y],keys=['x','y'],axis=1).reorder_levels([1,0],axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
Out[449]: 
    A       B    
    x   y   x   y
0  A0  A2  B0  B2
1  A1  A3  B1  B3
```

Comment: This looks also useful. I just want to add the link of [reorder_levels](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reorder_levels.html)

Comment: @hong sweet link :-) happy coding